# How to have multiple gravity forms on a particular page?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, gravity

I am using wordpress gravity forms plugin. I want to embed 2 gravity forms on a single page in my template. This is what I am using for embedding forms in my page ( http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Embedding_A_Form ). The issue is all the hooks which gravity forms provide have only one form object. 
Is there a way I can have multiple form objects on my page and I am also adding placeholder to my gravity form using this method (http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-placeholder-text-in-gravity-forms/). So now  I want to add placeholders to both the forms which are on same page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this plugin for place-holders: Gravity Forms - Placeholders add-on

(asked Nov 28 '12): Have you managed to get them displaying on 1 page?